# Check if any object in an array of objects contains all of the key/value pairs in another object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm trying to write a function that looks through an array of objects (the first argument) and returns an array of all objects that contain all of the key/value pairs of a given object (the second argument).

My code below works only if the `source` object (the second argument) contains one key/value pair. When the `source` object has two or more key/value pairs, the result isn't as expected.

How to account for more than one key/value pair in the `source` object?

```
function findObjects(collection, source) {
  var result = [];

  for (i=0; i<collection.length; i++) {
    for (var prop in source) {
      if (collection[i].hasOwnProperty(prop) && collection[i][prop] == source[prop]) {
        console.log('Collection\'s object ' + [i] + ' contains the source\'s key:value pair ' + prop + ': ' + source[prop] + '!');
        result.push(collection[i]);
      } else {
        console.log('fail');
      }
    }
  }

  console.log('The resulting array is: ' + result);
  return result;
}

findObjects([{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }, { "a": 1 }, { "b": 2, "c": 2 }], { "a": 1, "b": 2 });

// only the first object should be returned since it contains both "a":1 and "b":2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function findObjects(collection, source) {
    var result = [];

    for (i=0; i<collection.length; i++) {
        var matches = true;
        for (var prop in source) {
            if (!collection[i].hasOwnProperty(prop) || collection[i][prop] !== source[prop]) {
                matches = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (matches) {
            result.push(collection[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Basically, you have to check ALL properties and make sure they match, and then only *then* do you add it to your `result` array.

Comment: Yo! Jashaszun was the first to repond with a working solution. (Thanks!)

I also tested RomanPerekhrest's response and Nina Scholz's response, and both of those worked as well. I appreciate the opportunity to learn from the 3 different approaches.

Comment: Peace FreeCodeCampers!!

Answer (score 3):

You could use some array methods, like [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> The **`map()`** method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

and [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

> The **`every()`** method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function.

and get the properties of source first with [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

> The **`Object.keys()`** method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties, in the same order as that provided by a [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

```js
function findObjects(collection, source) {
    var keys = Object.keys(source);          // get all properties of source
    return collection.filter(function (c) {  // filter collection
        return keys.every(function (k) {     // check every key
            return c[k] === source[k];       // compare value of collection and source
        });
    });
}

console.log(findObjects([{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }, { "a": 1 }, { "b": 2, "c": 2 }], { "a": 1, "b": 2 }));
```

The same in ES6 syntax (read more: [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions))

> Basically this style is a short writing of
>
> ```
> function (x) { return y; }
> ```
>
> became
>
> ```
>           x =>        y
> ```

```js
function findObjects(collection, source) {
    const keys = Object.keys(source);
    return collection.filter(c => keys.every(k => c[k] === source[k]));
}

console.log(findObjects([{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }, { "a": 1 }, { "b": 2, "c": 2 }], { "a": 1, "b": 2 }));
```

Comment: In your first response, you've got three `return` statements, and I don't understand what's going on. If you have the time, would you please explain what's happening with your answer, ie, why it works?

Comment: Where are `(c)` and `(k)` each being passed from in your first response?
(And thanks for your helpful additional comments.)

Comment: `c` and `k` are parameters.

Comment: What is fulfilling those parameters? Is it that the `collection` array only has objects as enumerable properties, and the `source` object only has properties as enumerable properties, and so javascript Just Knows what to pass as the parameters by process-of-elimination because there isn't anything else to pass as the params?  **EDIT** Because `c` represents each object in `collection` and `k` represents each property in `source`, right?

Comment: right `c` is an element of `collection` and `k` is an element of `keys`, which are the keys of `source`. both parts of es5 and es6 works exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `Object.keys`, `Array.forEach` and `Array.some` functions:

```
function findObjects(arr, source) {
    var keys = Object.keys(source), result = [];
    arr.forEach(function(v){
        !keys.some((k) => source[k] !== v[k]) && result.push(v);
    });

    return result;
}

console.log(findObjects([{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }, { "a": 1 }, { "b": 2, "c": 2 }], { "a": 1, "b": 2 }));
// it will output [{"a":1,"b":2}]
```